# Array Input off by one index in C. Caesar Block Shift

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, multidimensional-array

Here I have code that inputs from stdin a stream of characters into an array. It then converts that array to a 2d array. Then it changes that array from row column order to column row order. Then it prints out the new array creating a Caesar shift encryption. The issue I am having is that my array is starting to input characters into the array with the second user typed character and I am not sure why.

For Example, if I type "Hello" into the console, only "ello" is put into the array.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
//
//  main.c
//  Caesar Block Cypher
//
//  Created by Jacob Byerline on 10/20/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Jacob Byerline. All rights reserved.
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
//The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional

char *str;
int inputChar;
int i, j;
size_t size = 0;
size_t len = 0;

printf("input string : ");
inputChar = getchar();

str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
if(!str)return *str;

while(EOF!=(inputChar=fgetc(stdin)) && inputChar != '\n'){

    if(isalpha(inputChar)){

        str[len++]=inputChar;

        if(len==size){

            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return *str;
        }
    }

}
str[len++]='\0';

int squareOfLen = sqrt(len);
int twoDimensionalArraySize = squareOfLen + 1;

//printf("%lu \n", len);
//printf("%d \n", squareOfLen);
//printf("%d \n", twoDimensionalArraySize);

char twoDstr[twoDimensionalArraySize][twoDimensionalArraySize];
char FINALtwoDstr[twoDimensionalArraySize][twoDimensionalArraySize];

memcpy(twoDstr, str, twoDimensionalArraySize * 2 * sizeof(int));

for(i=0; i<twoDimensionalArraySize; i++){
    for(j=0; j<twoDimensionalArraySize; j++){
        printf("2D Array[%d][%d] = %c\n",i,j,twoDstr[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=0; i<twoDimensionalArraySize; i++){
    for(j=0; j<twoDimensionalArraySize; j++){
        FINALtwoDstr[i][j] = twoDstr[j][i];
        //printf("2D Array[%d][%d] = %c\n",i,j,FINALtwoDstr[i][j]);
        printf("%c",FINALtwoDstr[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if(!str)return *str;` really? Try translating this to plain English.

Comment: What should the second dimension of the 2d table be? The same dimension as the string or 26 to get a representation of all possible Caesar shifts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
inputChar = getchar();
```

This is taking up 'H' from your input stream.

See here https://ideone.com/ZwT9Iq

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
//The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional

char *str;
int inputChar;
int i, j;
size_t size = 0;
size_t len = 0;

printf("input string : ");
//inputChar = getchar();

str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
if(!str)return *str;

while(EOF!=(inputChar=fgetc(stdin)) && inputChar != '\n'){

    if(isalpha(inputChar)){

        str[len++]=inputChar;

        if(len==size){

            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return *str;
        }
        printf("%c", inputChar);

    }

}
 printf("\n");
str[len]='\0';

int squareOfLen = sqrt(len);
int twoDimensionalArraySize = squareOfLen + 1;

//printf("%lu \n", len);
//printf("%d \n", squareOfLen);
//printf("%d \n", twoDimensionalArraySize);

char twoDstr[twoDimensionalArraySize][twoDimensionalArraySize];
char FINALtwoDstr[twoDimensionalArraySize][twoDimensionalArraySize];

memcpy(twoDstr, str, twoDimensionalArraySize * 2 * sizeof(int));

for(i=0; i<twoDimensionalArraySize; i++){
    for(j=0; j<twoDimensionalArraySize; j++){
        printf("2D Array[%d][%d] = %c\n",i,j,twoDstr[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=0; i<twoDimensionalArraySize; i++){
    for(j=0; j<twoDimensionalArraySize; j++){
        FINALtwoDstr[i][j] = twoDstr[j][i];
        //printf("2D Array[%d][%d] = %c\n",i,j,FINALtwoDstr[i][j]);
        printf("%c",FINALtwoDstr[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n");
return 0;

}
```

output

```
Hleol
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It fixed the issue but now I have run into another issue. So I fixed the code by deleting that line you mentioned. It works well except that the last value of the array is filling up with a random ascii character and printing out. For example, If i enter "hello" it will output "hleol*" or "hleol}" or "hleol/355" or some random value. Any thoughts?

Comment: did you change str[len++]='\0'; to str[len]='\0'; ? len already incremented once while exiting the loop. you dont wanna increment it after '\0'

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring allocation and check for alpha-ness, you do this:

```
inputChar = getchar();                    // Read first char

while (EOF != (inputChar=fgetc(stdin))    // read further chars
    && inputChar != '\n') {
        str[len++]=inputChar;
}
```

That means that the first character is consumed, but never stored. Instead, you could do this:

```
inputChar = getchar();                    // Read first char

while (inputChar != EOF && inputChar != '\n') {
        str[len++]=inputChar;
        inputChar=fgetc(stdin)            // read further chars
}
```

But there are other issues with your code:

- You start with an allocation of zero bytes, because `size` is 0;
- You should allocate before you store, otherwise you write beyond the end of the buffer;
- When you add the null terminator, you probably shouldn't increase `len`, because the `'\0'` isn't part of the locical length of the string, even if you have to allocate space for it, which you don't in all cases;
- The square of len is `len * len`, not `sqrt(len)`: That's the square root;
- You square the dimension twice: If `len` is 3, you want an 3×3 array, but you try to allocate a 9×9 array on the stack;
- You can't copy `len*len * 2 * sizeof(int)` bytes from `str`, which has only `len` bytes.

There's probably more in the last part; I haven't looked too closely.